# Conversion from a Grid View to PDF file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a Grid View to a PDF file. I tried to implement this using the code below, but it results in an error saying that

> no pdf exists

Does anyone know what might be going wrong, or how I could approach this?

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=UserDetails.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gvdetails.AllowPaging = false;
gvdetails.DataBind();
gvdetails.RenderControl(hw);
gvdetails.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
gvdetails.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
gvdetails.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
gvdetails.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
gvdetails.Style.Add("font-size", "8px");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();

pdfDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should move `gvdetails.RenderControl(hw);` after the block where you set `gvdetails` properties, otherwise the style settings will not be rendered to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataSet ds = GetCandidateData();
    DataTable candidateDT = ds.Tables[0];
    DataTable dtactivate = ds.Tables[1];

    totalCand = candidateDT.Rows.Count;

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    grvCandidate.AllowPaging = false;
    grvCandidate.DataSource = candidateDT;
    grvCandidate.DataBind();
    grvCandidate.RenderBeginTag(htmlWrite);
    grvCandidate.HeaderRow.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grvCandidate.Rows)
    {
        row.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    }
    grvCandidate.FooterRow.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    grvCandidate.RenderEndTag(htmlWrite);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(stringWrite.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```